# Dependent dropdown filters Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

What is the best way to write code for a scenario like this?

```
const data = [
 {
   brand : "ford", 
   model : "fiesta", 
   color : "silver"
 },
 {
   brand : "ford", 
   model : "fiesta", 
   color : "grey"
 },
 {
   brand : "ford", 
   model : "mustang", 
   color : "black"
 },
 {
   brand : "toyota", 
   model : "camry", 
   color : "blue"
 }
];
```

With this data, we are required to create a data set something like this to use it in a filter dropdown to hit the data service.

```
const filter = {
  brand : {
   key: "brand", 
   name : "Brand", 
   items :[
    "ford", 
    "toyota"
   ], 
   selected : "ford"
  }
},
model : {
   key: "model", 
   name : "Model", 
   items :[
    "fiesta", 
    "mustang"
   ], 
   selected : "fiesta"
  }
},
color : {
   key: "color", 
   name : "Color", 
   items :[
    "grey", 
    "silver"
   ], 
   selected : "grey"
  }
}
```

This would be the default set of filters and if you see model values are cascaded on selected brand and color values are cascaded on selected model.

There can be more than 3 columns in the data like engine capacity etc...

Here for example when a user select a value from model, we are required to cascade items of color and change the selected value of color only if it is not available in the cascaded list.

This is my approach and it seems kind of messed up, I was thinking of js currying but i dont think we can apply currying here

```
const filterDataOrganizer = {
 getBrands(data, selectedBrand) {
  const items = data.map(dt =>dt["brand"]).sort();
  const selected = items.includes(selectedBrand) ? selectedBrand : items[items.length - 1];
  return { items, selected };
 },
 getModels(data, selectedBrand, selectedModel) {
  const items = [
   ... new Set(
    data.map(dt =>
     if(dt["brand"] === selectedBrand) {
      return dt["model"]
     }
     return "";
    ).filter(dt => { 
      return dt !== "";
     }
    )
    .sort()
   ) 
  ];
  const selected = items.includes(selectedModel) ? selectedModel : items[items.length - 1];
  return { items, selected };
 },
 getColors(data, selectedBrand, selectedModel, selectedColor) {
  const items = [
   ... new Set(
    data.map(dt =>
     if(
      dt["brand"] === selectedBrand &&
      dt["model"] === selectedModel
     ) {
      return dt["color"]
     }
     return "";
    ).filter(dt => { 
      return dt !== "";
     }
    )
    .sort()
   ) 
  ];
  const selected = items.includes(selectedColor) ? selectedColor : items[items.length - 1];
  return { items, selected };
 }
 filterHandler(data, filterData = {}, key) {
  const {
   brand,
   model,
   color
  } = filterData;
   
  if(key === "brand") {
   model = this.getModels(data, brand["selected"]);
   color = this.getColors(data, brand["selected"], color["selected"]);
  } else if(key === "color") {
   color = this.getColors(data, brand["selected"], color["selected"]);
  } else {
   // default filters
   brand = this.getBrands(data);
   model = this.getModels(data, brand["selected"]);
   color = this.getColors(data, brand["selected"], color["selected"]);
  }
  return {
   brand, 
   model, 
   color
  }
}
```

Comment: In the desired output, you have unbalanced braces. It is not a valid JavaScript object.